# Ho to use array dict in sgqlc.operation module in graphql

Tags: python, graphql

I have the sampe code like this

```
from sgqlc.types import *


class DamageNodes(Input):
    item = str
    damage = str


class GraphqlNodes(Type):
    point = int
    damages = Field(list_of(DamageNodes), args={'item': str, 'damage': str})


class Query(Type):
    type_model = Field(GraphqlNodes, args={'type_a': str,
                                        'type_b': str})


query = Operation(Query)

dict_sample = {
   "item": "Headliner",
   "damage": "Stained"
}

query.type_model(type_a='modelA', type_b='modelB').__fields__(damages=dict_sample)
print(query)
```

Output:

```
query {
  typeModel(typeA: "modelA", typeB: "modelB") {
    damages(item: "Headliner", damage: "Stained") {
      item
      damage
    }
  }
}
```

In my case, is it possible to use array dict in **fields**

```
dict_sample = [{
     "item": "Headliner",
     "damage": "Stained"
    },
    { "item": "A",
      "damage": "B"
    }]

query.type_model(type_a='modelA', type_b='modelB').__fields__(damages=dict_sample)
print(query)
```

Expected output

```
query {
  typeModel(typeA: "modelA", typeB: "modelB") {
    damages([{item: "Headliner", damage: "Stained"},{item: "A", damage: "B"}]) {
      item
      damage
    }
  }
}
```

But it can not and this is the actual output

```
query {
  typeModel(typeA: "modelA", typeB: "modelB") {
    damages(item: "damage") {
      item
      damage
    }
  }
}
```

I understand that it only use dict in **fields** , But is there any case or workaround to use array dict in grapql

Docs :
https://sgqlc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sgqlc.operation.html#mutations